# Correlations for multiple indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

I'm new to Python, and I've got problems in calculating correlation coefficients for multiple participants.
I've got a dataframe just like this :

```
|Index|Participant|Condition|ReactionTime1|ReactionTime2|
|:---:|:---------:|:-------:|:-----------:|:-------------:|
|1|1|A|320|542|
|2|1|A|250|623|
|3|1|B|256|547|
|4|1|B|301|645|
|5|2|A|420|521|
|6|2|A|123|456|
|7|2|B|265|362|
|8|2|B|402|631|
```

I am wondering how to calculate correlation coefficient between Reaction Time 1 and Reaction Time2 for Participant 1 and for Participant 2 in each condition. My real dataset is way bigger than this (hundreds of Reaction Time for each participant, and there are a lot of participant too). Is there a general way to calculate this and to put coeff in a new df like this?

```
|Index|Participant|Condition|Correlation coeff|
|:---:|:---------:|:-------:|:-----------:|
|1|1|A|?|
|2|1|B|?|
|3|2|A|?|
|4|2|B|?|
```

Thanks :)

Comment: with many reaction columns you'll get a symmetric NxN matrix of correlation coefficients, not just a single value, so what would your output look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `groupby` and `apply` with `np.corrcoef`, and `reset_index` afterwards:

```py
result = (df.groupby(["Participant", "Condition"])
            .apply(lambda gr: np.corrcoef(gr["ReactionTime1"], gr["ReactionTime2"])[0, 1])
            .reset_index(name="Correlation coeff"))
```

which gives

```
   Participant Condition  Correlation coeff
0            1         A               -1.0
1            1         B                1.0
2            2         A                1.0
3            2         B                1.0
```

We use `[0, 1]` on the returned value of `np.corrcoef` since it returns a symmetric matrix where diagonal elements are normalized to 1 and off-diagonal elements are the same and each gives the desired coefficient (so might as well index with `[1, 0]`). That is,

```
array([[1.        , 0.25691558],
       [0.25691558, 1.        ]])
```

is an example returned value and we are interested in the off-diagonal entry.

Why it returned all `+/- 1` in your case: since each participant & conditon pair only has 2 entries for each reaction, they are *always* perfectly correleated and the sign is determined via their orientation i.e. if one increases from one coordinate to the other coordinate, does other one increase or decrease.

Comment: It's working perfectly with my real dataset. Thanks a lot!!